# Ruby: is there a stemmer that "knows" English irregular verbs?

Tags: ruby, nlp, stemming

There is a ruby stemmer https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer, but it 1) does not stem English irregular verbs 2) fails to build native extensions on Windows. Is there an alternative that fixes at least one of the problems?

Comment: Why? Are you using it for Machine Learning? Is there some research that shows that it would help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be searching for a lemmatizer (which has information about morphology and can handle irregular words) rather than a stemmer (which usually just lops off the ends of words).  See [this explanation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) in Manning, Raghavan, and Schütze's online book on information retrieval.

I haven't tried it out, but a quick search came across this English lemmatizer for Ruby: [elemma](http://mastarpj.nict.go.jp/~mutiyama/software.html#elemma).

A commonly-used (non-Ruby) English morphological analyzer that can do lemmatization is [morpha](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html).

Answer (score 4):

None of the stemmers are able to handle irregular verbs in English.

- https://github.com/ealdent/uea-stemmer - pure ruby, well-written, 2009 year, has little docs, but a bit more then others, installs on Windows OK
- https://github.com/romanbsd/fast-stemmer pure C, difficult to read, ought to be quicker then others (I did not tested performance), from 2009 year, has very minimal docs, installs on Windows OK. **it's method has side-effects. be careful to create a copy**
- https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer 2010 year, it fails to build native extensions on Windows. Can handle som other European languages except English
- http://rubyforge.org/projects/stemmer pure ruby, has not been updated since 2006, and does not have any documentation, installs OK on Windows, I did not figured out how it works
- http://rubyforge.org/projects/stemmer4r - no docs, 2005 year. did not try

Answer (score 1):

i found this while googling for ruby based NLP http://mendicantbug.com/2009/09/13/nlp-resources-for-ruby/